# NSFetchedResultsController - NSSortDesciptor One-To-Many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

In my data model I have a **Customer** object and each customer can have many **Address** objects mapped as a one to many relationship.

I am using **NSFetchedResultsController** to get the data for each **Customer**. However I want to sort the response by **city** on the **Address** object.

Please can you show me how this can be done (if possible ta ll). I've tried a few ways but with no real luck.

Thanks

Comment: It makes no sense to sort by a to-many relationship: there are many addresses for a given customer, which one should be used for the sort?

Comment: I need to sort by city, which is an attribute of Address

Comment: Yes, but there can be many addresses, and therefore many cities.  Which one should be used?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just the first one should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, that was a rhetorical question.  There is no way to sort by (an attribute of) a to-many relationship.  You could instead add an attribute to the Customer entity, eg. "primaryCity", and update that when adding/removing addresses from the relationship.  Then sort by primaryCity.

Comment: 
yup thats what I thought

Thanks anyway